# Days old udacity

Tags: python

I have a problem in these two cases`print daysBetweenDates(2011, 1, 1, 2012, 8, 8)
    print daysBetweenDates(1900,1,1, 1999,12, 31)`when I put them with the other test cases I got a wrong answer by 1 day extra and sometimes by 2 days.sometimes one of them give me the right answer but it also appears as`Test with data:(2011, 1, 1, 2012,8,8)failed
Test with data: (1900, 1, 1, 1999, 12, 31) failed` but when I test each case alone i got the right answer.

```
daysofmonths = [ 0,31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
def leap_year(year):
    leap_day = 366
    common_day = 365
    if year % 4 != 0:
        return common_day
    elif year % 100 != 0:
        return leap_day
    elif year % 400 !=0:
        return common_day
    else:
        return leap_day
def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    #code for same year
    if year1 == year2:
        if month1 == month2:
            return day2 - day1
        days = daysofmonths[month1] - day1 
        month1 = month1 + 1
        while month1 < month2: 
            if leap_year(year1) == 366:
                daysofmonths[2] = 29 
            days = days + daysofmonths[month1] 
            month1 = month1 + 1
        return days + day2
  ################################################
    days = daysofmonths[month1] - day1
    month1 = month1 + 1
    while month1 <= 12:
        if leap_year(year1) == 366:
            daysofmonths[2] = 29
        days = days  + daysofmonths[month1] 
        month1 = month1 + 1
    #print days 
    year1 = year1 + 1 
    ###########################################################
    days = days + day2 
    month2 = month2 - 1 
    while month2 >= 1:
        if leap_year(year2) == 366:
            daysofmonths[2] = 29
        days = days + daysofmonths[month2] 
        month2 = month2 - 1
    #print days
    year2 = year2 - 1 
    ###########################################################
    while year1 <= year2:
        days = days + leap_year(year1)
        year1 = year1 + 1
    return days 
print daysBetweenDates(2011, 1, 1, 2012, 8, 8)
print daysBetweenDates(1900,1,1, 1999,12, 31)

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do:

```
daysofmonths[2] = 29
```

it changes the element in the list, which then is used for every subsequent call, if you added `print(daysofmonths[2])` in between the test cases you would see that it is always `29` after the first case that needs to check February, so instead of conditionally changing the list with:

```
if leap_year(year1) == 366:
    daysofmonths[2] = 29 
days = days + daysofmonths[month1]
```

just conditionally add to `days`:

```
if leap_year(year1) == 366 and month1 == 2:
    days = days + 29
else:
    days = days + daysofmonths[month1]
```

then do the same thing lower down with `year2` and `month2` (I would highly recommend you separate your code into more functions as a lot of it is very repetitive)

Comment: Thank you for your help, You inspire me to make something else ,after every test in the code  I set again daysofmonths[2] = 28 and it works.

Comment: That is **not** a very good solution, the function still breaks its own functionality unless patched up by something else, are you sure that is how you want to code?

Comment: No, I want to code better of course. I am learning from guys like you.

Comment: actually I guess you could reset the value at the end of the function, that way it would at least be repairing it's own changes instead of relying on other code to fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only post I found here on this particular problem so I thought I would share my solution.

```
#days in the months of a non leap year
daysOfMonths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

#determine if a year is a leap year
def is_leap_year(year1):
    year = True
    if  year1 % 4 != 0:
        year = False
    elif year1 % 100 != 0:
        year = True
    elif year1 % 400 != 0:
        year = False
    else: year = True
    return year

#returns the days in the given month of the given year
#I was trying to do something similar to the OP until I read this post
def days_in_month(year, month):
    days = 0
    if is_leap_year(year) and month == 2:
        days += 29
    else:
        days += daysOfMonths[month - 1]
    return days

#itterates through each month starting at year1 month1
#up to but not including month2 of year2 and
#returns the total number of days in that period
def total_days(year1, month1, year2, month2):
    days = 0
    while year1 < year2 or month1 < month2:
        days += days_in_month(year1, month1)
        month1 += 1
        if month1 == 13:
            year1 += 1
            month1 = 1
    return days



def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):

    days = total_days(year1, month1, year2, month2)
#because I included the beginning month I have to subtract day1
#because I did not include the final month I have to add day2
    return days - day1 + day2

#I used print statements here to troubleshoot
#print days_in_month(2012, 1)
#print daysBetweenDates(2012, 1, 1, 2012, 2, 28) 
#print daysBetweenDates(2012, 1, 1, 2012, 3, 1) 
#print daysBetweenDates(2011,6,30,2012,6,30) 
#print daysBetweenDates(2011,1,1,2012,8,8) 
#print daysBetweenDates(1900,1,1,1999,12,31) 


def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```